# Modify the Lookup Column in SharePoint 2013

Tags: javascript, web-part, search-results, lookup-column, newform

**Hi everyone,**

in general I do like the lookup column, but I think sometime (especially with over 100 items in the lookup) its not that convenient.

In my lookup there are 300 items (title of the items from the same list). The user should pick similar items.

**Any ideas how to realize one of my ideas or other ideas would help me a lot!**

Ideas how to improve the convenience:

- I want to have a 'search option' on top of the lookup
- when entering the title (or description) of the item I want a search that shows me similar items (I can pick them in the lookup afterwards) .. maybe with javascript etc.?
- I want the 'text box' to be larger, because at the moment the user is not even able to view the whole title (because the column is too small)
- filter the lookup so that users only see items where some columns are similar

I just read that you can filter the lookup with calculated columns.. but I haven't figured out a way that this helps me with my problem..

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to modify the Lookup Column itself, just the Edit/New forms where the value is selected.

You can do this with SharePoint Designer or Client Side Rendering. Either approach would allow you to use JavaScript to create the input control you want.

One solution would be to use the jQuery UI autocomplete functionality tied to the REST API for the lookup list to retrieve values.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer!
I modified the New/Edit Forms with SharePoint Designer before, but unfortunately I'm not an expert.
If I write my javascript should I write it directly in the code or save it to my sharepoint and invoke it?

Thanks!

Comment: It won't take much code so you could get away with adding it directly. However, since you are already using it in 2 places (New and Edit forms) it would be better to upload this to a library (The root SC Style Library is a great spot). This will make code maintenance easier as well.